# Help me to drive the CCD ICX282AQ

Tags: arduino, microchip, ccd

This is the first time I am working with an image sensor. I have the [datasheet of the ICX282AQ](http://www.riddle.ru/dl/ccd/sony/icx282aq.pdf%E2%80%8E). But I don't understand much. What I would like to do is:

- Can I drive this sensor with an Arduino board to send data to my computer? Any device/chip is needed more to drive this sensor?
- Any tutorial to drive it, any open source, designed board?

Answer (score 1):

To drive this CCD you'll have to have a full understanding of its operational principles and a strong background in low-noise electronics. Driving the device is only part of the problem, as there are different voltage swings, edge rates and signal relationships that must be met or the device will perform poorly if at all. On top of that, there is the need to have some sort of sequencing/state machine and ADC on the other end coupled to a CDS circuit.

The nice thing about Sony devices is that they often also sell support chips that serve to form an operational camera. These would involve a digital sequencing chip, drivers, and analog CDS chip (sometimes with integrated ADC). With these wired together, you'd just need to provide the many different power supplies required.

Comment: "The nice thing about Sony devices is that they often also sell support chips that serve to form an operational camera. These would involve a digital sequencing chip, drivers, and analog CDS chip (sometimes with integrated ADC)." Can you give me more detail about it ? Do you have any tutorial for it ? Thank you so much